# Openerp 7.0 error database

Tags: postgresql, debian, odoo

i have a problem with Openerp, can you help me please ?

```
ERROR ? openerp.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf and make sure you have at least the following options set:

```
db_host = (usually localhost)
db_port = (usually 5432)
db_user =
db_password =
```

Try connecting to your database manually by running:

```
psql -d postgres -U <YOUR DATABASE USERNAME> -W
```

If this works (you should get a prompt like "postgres=>", exit it by pressing ctrl+d) but the error is still there in OpenERP, its probably because you run Ubuntu/Debian and you just installed your OpenERP package. The error appears because the init script are not able to kill the first openerp Python process started by dpkg automatically after the package installation. To fix this, run:

```
# ps aux|grep openerp
```

You will see a line that looks something like this:

```
openerp  14438  0.3  0.8 235096 69060 ?        Sl   03:23   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/openerp-server --config=/etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf --logfile=/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
```

The first number is the pid of the Python process. Kill the process by running:

```
kill -9 14438
```

Then restart your openerp server again by running:

```
/etc/init.d/openerp restart
```

Your `openerp-server.conf` should now be re-read by OpenERP and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Search Google and Stack Overflow for "fe_sendauth: no password supplied".

Your PostgreSQL is set up to require a password for the (address,database,user) combination you're connecting with and you aren't sending a password.

You can learn more by reading [the Client Authentication chapter of the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

Answer (score 0):

create a postgres user using this command.
make sure the user is named same to your system user.

```
sudo su postgres

createuser -d -S -R <your system user>

psql

alter user <your system user> with password <your password>;
```

Hope it will resolve your issue to establish connection with database.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your opererp-server.conf and look for addons_path. Make sure you have /openerp/addons and /openerp/web/addons. if you have something else just take it off and restart your server. It will work.